# Keras input dimensional layer

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

### **Problem**

I am using the Model API to create a Keras network that takes in two inputs and one output. When training the network I get the following error:

> Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you
> are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected
> to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:

Despite this error, the input X array has a shape of (2,8), and the output y array has a shape of (1,4).

### **Things already tried**

There are a number of similar questions on SO, however, their solutions largely revolves around ensuring X and y are Numpy arrays. As seen in my implementation, I have already done that. Thus, I do not believe this is a duplicate question.

### **Implementation**

I have defined the model as follows:

```
    opt = Adam(lr = alpha)
    input = Input(shape=(input_dim_,))
    delta = Input(shape=[1])
    l1 = Dense(units = 1024, input_dim = input_dim_, activation = "relu")(input)
    l2 = Dense(units=512, activation="relu")(l1)

    def loss_function (y,y_pred):
        y_pred = K.clip(y_pred,1e-8,1-1e-8)
        return K.sum(-y*K.log(y_pred)*delta)

    if model_type == "actor":
        out = Dense(units = output_dim_, activation="softmax")(l2)
        model = Model(input=[input,delta], output = [out])
        model.compile(loss = loss_function,optimizer=opt)
```

And train the model by doing the following:

```
X = [s_t,delta]
X = np.array(X)
actor.fit(X,y,verbose=0)
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can you provide bogus data of the correct shape so I can give it a try? With `np.random.rand()` or something.

Comment: @NicolasGervais 
X = np.random.rand(2,8)
y = np.random.rand(1,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the data correctly in fit:

```
actor.fit(X,y,verbose=0)
```

Here `X` should be a list containing two numpy arrays, and each numpy array corresponds to one of your inputs (you have a model with two inputs): So it should be more like this:

```
X = [np.array(s_t), np.array(delta)]
actor.fit(X, y, verbose=0)
```

Then it should work.